# Voltage difference between input and output of transformer

Tags: transformer, ac

[image]

I have been trying to find the voltage difference between the input and output terminals of transformers, but every google result just got to the primary vs secondary so I decided I would just ask here.

The voltage difference between the top input terminal and top output terminal. Maybe also if it is interesting the voltage difference between top input terminal and bottom output terminal. I guess it also depends on the dot convention. Is there even a voltage?

Edit: I made the image. I thought there might be some sort of sine wave between them, that is why I labeled like it. The positive and negative was just for v1 and v2. If two there are two power supplies that make use of transformers, can you use them in parallel (if they are same voltages) or in series without having "shorting" or common current problems?

Edit2 : I asked this because I wanted to learn if there is any relation between magnetic coupling and potential(does the magnetic field keep the potential) but I learned that the 2 circuits are isolated and the only thing providing energy is the magnetic coupling.
It makes sense to say that there will be a little capacitive coupling, but I guess that is very small. So I basically got my answer. Thanks everyone.

Comment: the transformer in your diagram is not connected to anything

Comment: Hi Gideon, you'll notice that different people here have different interpretations of what you use this for: Could you add the surrounding circuitry, or label precisely what you consider the input and what the output? your current notation doesn't allow for unambiguous reading, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an ideal transformer, there is no connection between the input terminals and the output terminals, so the voltage is undefined. It can be anything you want it to be, by connecting that voltage to it. This is what a mains isolating transformer does, allows the output to be at a different voltage to the input.

In practice, in a real transformer, there is some slight capacitive coupling between the input and output windings, and both windings and ground. If you measure the AC voltage between the windings with a high impedance voltmeter, you'll read something, usually some fraction of the input voltage.

Comment: OP seems to be using the transformer as a common mode choke (or similar configuration). There absolutely is a connection between input and output terminals in that configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The "input terminals" are connected to what we usually call "the primary (winding)"; the "output terminals" to the "secondary (winding)".

So, you already found the answers that define the *ratio* between the amplitude of the AC on the primary (input) winding and the secondary (output) winding.

That's all there is to it.

No absolute difference is defined. It can be anything. What is defined is a *ratio between voltages*, not a *difference in absolute potentials*. That's what transformers are for: changing voltages proportionally, without being affected by differences in potential.

By the way, your drawing of a transformer is very nonsensical. Transformers work with AC, not DC, so adding "+" or "-" to a drawing of one makes little sense (with the exception of chokes used in DC circuits, but you're talking about transformer usage, not choke usage). And putting the same sign on both contacts of the same winding doesn't even make sense. So, wherever that drawing is from: it's very confusing, and probably wrong learning material.

Comment: OP appears to be using the transformer like a common mode choke, so your first paragraph, and the rest of the discussion driver from those assumptions, don't apply to their use case.

Comment: I'm not sure, their edit honestly confuses me. "Sine wave between them" does sound like transformer usage to me…

Answer (score 0):

The two coils, primary (what you call "input") and secondary (your "output"), are electrically isolated from each other. There's no path for current between them (except for a tiny capacitance, which I'll mention in a moment), and as such their potential difference is undefined.

They are independent circuits, with nothing connecting them together, and it doesn't really make sense to ask what is the potential difference between them, in the same way it doesn't make sense to ask what is the potential difference between the earth and the moon.

So when you ask "is there even a voltage?", that's the right question, to which the answer is no, there isn't a voltage to be measured. In fact, the moment you place a voltmeter between the two sides, you have introduced a path for current between them, destroying their isolation. Ironically, the very the act of measuring would give meaning to the idea of a potential difference between the windings. And that difference would then be 0V (for a simple voltmeter between them).

<sub>Note: There is always *some* conductivity present between any two things, but it's tiny in this context, so tiny as to be negligible. There is also a slight capacitance between the windings, and that is a path for *changing* current. The potential difference across that capacitance will depend on many factors, to do with what else is connected to those coils, and the environment. Capacitance is always present, and will always make blanket statements like "it will be 0V" impractical, but it's a big topic, and not really in keeping with the spirit of the question.</sub>

Since there is nothing explicitly applying a potential difference between them, nothing's stopping you from doing so yourself:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5PxxG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By connecting something between the two windings, I have removed their independence, and now it certainly *does* make sense to talk of a potential difference between them. On the left, by connecting node A to node B, I can say with certainty that the potential difference between the top ends of the coils is 0V. On the right, I can claim that node D is always 5V higher in potential than node C.

You wouldn't normally do this, though, unless you have a very good reason, because this isolation between the two sides is a very useful property. For instance, if the primary side is connected to high mains voltages, and the secondary side is powering your low voltage radio, the controls and the case of the radio are completely disconnected from any dangerous mains voltages, and it will be safe to touch and manipulate the radio's case, knobs and buttons without fear of electrocution.

Comment: OP appears to be using the transformer as a common mode choke (or similar configuration) so your statement that the two sides are electrically isolated doesn't apply to their use case.

Answer (score 0):

Despite what 4 other answers have said, the input-output configuration you drew is perfectly valid. Its main use (at least in my experience) is as a [*common-mode choke*](https://www.coilcraft.com/en-us/edu/series/a-guide-to-understanding-common-mode-chokes/). That is, a circuit that allows differential signal to pass through, but blocks common mode signals.

Normally we draw the transformer "sideways" for this configuration:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd28LU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If this circuit is ideal there is no voltage difference from input to output for differential signals, and a substantial difference for AC common-mode signals. Because there is no isolation from input to output, DC common-mode signals are not blocked, allowing DC bias to be maintained between input and output.

Any difference in the differential signal between input and output is due to parasitics such as the winding resistance of the transformer.